# Can somebody help me with the execute commands in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently, Minecraft had removed the `/testfor` command, which broke these sets of commands that I was trying to execute today.

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:feather",tag:{display:{Name:"Roc's Feather",Lore:[Jump higher using this feather.]}}}}`
```

Now normally, from Minecraft 1.13 onwards, the new `/execute` command would've been the replacement for the `/testfor` command, but as I soon found out, the command failed to detect my `Roc's Feather` and thus could not execute an `/effect` command that gave me a Jump Boost, for 1 second, at level 3.

I tried remaking my feather from scratch with this command here:

```
/give @p minecraft:feather{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Roc's Feather\",\"color\":\"light_purple\",\"bold\":true,\"italic\":true,\"underlined\":false,\"strikethrough\":false,\"obfuscated\":false}",Lore:["{\"text\":\"Jump higher using this feather.\",\"bold\":false,\"italic\":true,\"underlined\":false,\"strikethrough\":false,\"obfuscated\":false}"]}} 1
```

But the execute command I placed did not detect this type of uniqueness.

```
/execute if entity @p[distance=10,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:feather",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Roc's Feather\",\"color\":\"light_purple\",\"bold\":true,\"italic\":true,\"underlined\":false,\"strikethrough\":false,\"obfuscated\":false}",Lore:["{\"text\":\"Jump higher using this feather.\",\"bold\":false,\"italic\":true,\"underlined\":false,\"strikethrough\":false,\"obfuscated\":false}"]}}}}] run effect give @s minecraft:jump_boost 1 3 true
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here because I cannot even tell what's the issue.

Comment: Why would you want to use `r=10000000000`? I'm pretty sure the lore also previously had to be in quotation marks. Can you reduce the command to the minimum reproduction example, please? It's extremely long, with such a length a simple typo is the most likely cause for every error.

Comment: Lowered the distance numbers for you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how were you targeting the player that is holding the feather, or was this intended to be single player only?  I ask because I previously would have done this with scoreboard tags, and that method, for the most part, would not need to be changed with 1.13.  Also, I have a general distaste for using `testfor`.

Comment: Zelda map. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you might try  in that final command is to change it from saying `@a[distance=10]` to `@a[distance=..10]` because in 1.13 they changed it so that ..10 is less than 10, 10 is exactly 10, and 10.. is greater than ten, with 1..10 being between 1 and 10. So unless you are exactly 10 blocks away nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

there are three things actually;

1. keep in mind that you also need quotes around your text formatting, eg; `{\"bold\":\"true\"}`.
2. you don't necessarily need to add formatting if they're false; those tags don't exist if they're false, really, and just clog up your text.
3. currently, saying `distance=10` is looking for everyone at *exactly* 10 blocks. if you want people at **more** than 10, you need `10..`, and for **less**, `..10`.

hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your method. Unfortunately the command block wasn't able to detect my feather despite the changes I made that I followed.

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty obsessed with this problem so I did some tinkering.

I eventually whittled down to the command:

`/execute as @p[distance=..10,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:feather"}}] run effect give @s minecraft:jump_boost 1 3 true`

This includes suggestions from the other answers, but there are a few notable changes here.
Firstly note that I'm not using the complete name of the item, for the sake of quick debugging.

Nextly, I wasn't sure what a `count:1b` meant, rather than 1, so I eliminated it. I'd love to know.

Most importantly, I changed from `execute if entity @p[...]` to `execute as @p[...]`. I did this because I noticed that in the latter half of the execute command (`run effect give @s ...`), that there is the `@s` target. This fails because the executor of the command is the command block, not the player. As `@s` gives the effect to the caster (here the command block), no player receives the effect. I changed the former half of the command (`execute if entity ...`) to `execute as @p[...]` here to make the player into the caster, effectively making `@s` the player.

I was further tempted to then try the simplified command, which was successful:

`/effect give @p[distance=..10,nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:feather"}}] minecraft:jump_boost 1 3 true`

The distance constraint seems excessive at this point, but I left it for creator's sake.

Thank you for loving one of my favourite games, Link's Awakening, and for inspiring me to help bring the spirit of LA into my Minecraft world. I hope to see great content from you in the future.

Comment: After more research, I've learned a few more things: For the count, 1b is the formally correct way to specify a count of 1. The 'b' indicates that the number is in the bytes format, rather than an integer.